# How to create a layout with some space(gap) above it . Not with in the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to create a layout with some space above it. Normally, the layout occupies the whole screen. But, I want to leave some gap above the layout so that it does not touch the top of the screen.
I've searched for it, found nothing.

Please tell me a way to achieve that.

Thanks in advance.

I want this kind of output

[image]

Comment: post the XML code or related java code so that your post can be reopened by other members with a reason

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh thanks for suggestions BTW The op doesn't mention that that why i have make it dup and  i know ` great power comes with responsibility`  that

Answer (score 0):

Just add a margin in the layouts xml. Can also go into design and select the layout itself (constraint by default) and add padding and margins. Margin would be the best option as it'll move the whole viewgroup.